Facebook Webhook Not Triggering for Comments Containing Video (GIFs, etc) – Alternative Solutions?
I am currently developing an app that interacts with Facebook Page content and messages using Facebook webhooks to receive event notifications when users engage with the page.
While I’ve successfully set up and received webhooks for most events, such as page messages and feed comments, I’m experiencing an issue where the webhook is not triggered when someone posts a comment that contains a video or GIF. It seems Facebook doesn’t send any event notifications when these types of media are included in the comment except PHOTO.
I’ve noticed other developers have reported similar issues in these threads, but there is no clear solution:

Thread 1
Thread 2

My goal:
I need to capture comments that contain videos, GIFs, or stickers as soon as they are published. Actively polling for comments using the Graph API is not an ideal solution due to rate limits and the need for near real-time behavior.
Question:
Has anyone found a solution or workaround for receiving these types of comments (with videos, GIFs, or stickers) in real-time using Facebook’s webhooks? Is there any other method to capture them efficiently without constantly querying the Graph API?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
